# a4j:ajax render h:outputText on keyup of h:inputText inside a4j:repeat

Tags: ajax, jsf, ajax4jsf

I would like to render the value of `<h:outputText>` as I type in the `<h:inputText>`. Below is code I have written. The bean is session scoped. As I type in `<h:inputText>`, the `<h:outputText>` is not changed. Initial value `#{item.AB}` is only shown.

I referred [RichFaces 4 Overview. Part I – Ajax Request Queuing](http://in.relation.to/2010/06/25/rich-faces-4-overview-part-i-ajax-request-queuing) to write the code.

```
<a4j:repeat rowKeyVar="index" var="item" value="#{EX.EXlist}">
    <h:inputText id="AB#{index}" value="#{item.AB}">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="CA#{index}" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="CA#{index}" value="#{item.AB}" />
</a4j:repeat>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why suffixing `#{index}` over all place? Which misinformed resource exactly is guiding you that? Remove them all and retry. It should work just fine.

Comment: Actually the inputtext and outputtext forms a row in the table. There will be multiple rows generated based on the size of `#{EX.EXlist}`. i need to render the value of the input text to the corresponding outputtext of the same row

Comment: So you just "invented" all by yourself..? JSF has already solved the naming container problem for long. Once again, get rid of `#{index}` suffix over all place and retry. It should work just fine. You don't need this boilerplate in JSF. As evidence, open page in webbrowser, do rightclick and *View Source* to see the JSF-generated HTML output. You'll see that JSF already took care of the uniqueness of generated HTML element IDs. If it still doesn't work, then the problem is caused elsewhere and you must then reframe the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. can i add something like this to the above code `<h:outputText id="CA"  value="#{item.AB}" >`<br/>`<a4j:ajax event="change" render="ZA" />` `<h:outputText>` `<h:outputText id="ZA"  value="#{EX.ZA}" />`   so that on change of the CA outputtext the ZA outputtext changes